# Mass Delete Data Extensions

Tags: dataextensions, delete

Does anyone have a way to mass delete out thousands of data extensions.  They are not all in the same folder but all follow the same naming convention.

Answer (score 1):

Using the SOAP Api retrieve all the DataExtension objects you want deleted.  You need the Ids of the objects youll recieve in your Retrieve call.  There are multiple ways to do this, you can either use some filtering in the SOAP call or you can simply ask for all DataExtension objects then manually comb through them to compile a list of Ids.

Once you have the Ids of the DataExtensions you wish deleted, you can then use the SOAP Api to make a Delete call, deleting these DataExtensions.

I would write a small application to do it for me (with a lot of testing prior to deleting things!), but you can also very easily do it more manually by simply making SOAP calls through Postman or some similar application.